# Добавление кнопок на скрол большого изображения

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

На большой карте необходимо разместить множество кнопок. Карта скролится по горизонтали. Через сториборд получится лишь немного накидать кнопок, а при скроле изображения в открываемых участках кнопок уже не установить. Как Создать кнопки на всем изображении карты? Спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как Вы добавляете кнопки? Почему при скролле не установить?

Comment: Через сториборд установил штук десять, отображаются при запуске на левой части карты. А начинаешь скролить в право карту, там остается пустая область без кнопок, тк там кнопки в сториборде не устанавливались, карта широкая и на сториборде правой части не видно

Comment: AutoLayout'ы не применяете?  Top Left Width Height = const

Comment: Все решил через сториборд, увеличил размер контроллера до размера картинки, накидал кнопки где надо на скролвью и все работает. Спасибо